# How do I include an image in a window with pygtk?

Tags: python, image, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to make a program in python which creates a fullscreen window and includes an image, but I don't really know how to do that. I've tried to read documentations on pygtk and I've searched in both goodle and stackoverflow, without any success.
Here's my current code.

```
def __init__(self):
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("test.png")
    image = gtk.Image()
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.fullscreen()
    self.window.show()
    image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
    image.show()
```

Question: how do I include an image in a window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please provide a little more context (e.g. class definition, imports).

Do not forget to add the `image` object to your window (before showing image and window):

```
self.window.add(image)
```

The [tutorial example](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-Images.html#id2843382) adds the image to a `button`, but you can try adding it directly to the main window:

```
# an image widget to contain the pixmap
image = gtk.Image()
image.set_from_pixmap(pixmap, mask)
image.show()

# a button to contain the image widget
button = gtk.Button()
button.add(image)
window.add(button)
button.show()

button.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm.
If you want to, you can see the whole code [here.](http://pastebin.com/TnM8tdAu)

Comment: A little context as part of a question helps in understanding. Glad to provide a solution ;-)